Where should the interior NM-B rated wire connect to exterior rated wiring?
This question is a continuation of this one. It looks like the  6AWG cable that I ran down the wall through a one inch conduit is not rated for wet conditions. I also ran across some information stating that Romex through conduit doesn't make sense as it duplicates the wire sheathing and can lead to heat issues. I'm wondering a few things then:

Where is the best place to transition from the NM-B rated cable to the wire approved for wet conditions (i.e. the conduit running down the exterior wall)? Can I do it in the 90 degree conduit body where the conduit leaves the wall (see picture)?

What wire rating should I use in the exterior conduit? And what makes it different from what's in the Romex insulation? Can I just peel the Romex of its insulation and use the three wires as they are?




The transition should take place inside the house - on the house side of the drainage plane of the wall.
The LB is beyond that plane to the exterior. It's also too small for a 6AWG junction box. So you need a large-enough junction box inside the house. You need 5 cubic inches in the box for every 6AWG wire "count" (so 25 cubic inches for a 6/2 with ground, and 35 for a 6/3 with ground. Assuming the cable clamp sticks out of, not into the box, anyway.) Look for "box fill calculation" if that's news to you.
No, you cannot strip the sheath of NM/B and use it in conduit (unless the individual wires in the cable were individually marked with an appropriate rating, and they never are.)
You can use any wet-rated wire you like, though market forces will tend to put you at THWN-2 or XHHW these days for available types, but you may be able to find RWH or TW somewhere if you like to take up more space in conduit for a wire that's not good to as high temperatures.

In theory, you could use the wires from inside non-metallic cable (Romex) by themselves. In practice, you can't. That's because the individual wires don't usually have any printed indication of the type of wire, and for outdoor locations you are required by code to use wire that is rated for wet locations, because outdoor conduit is assumed to at some point get wet inside due to condensation and/or rain.
Which means you need wire rated THWN or XHHW - in both cases the W is for water resistance.
As for where it is needed, the official rule, as I understand it, is anywhere outside the walls of a building. In practice, when there is a junction box on the outside of a building with an outlet (e.g., 15A or 20A 120V receptacle) or inlet (generator) and the cable goes through the wall directly into the back of the box, with no cable outside the box (even in conduit), that is allowed. But that's about it.
If you want to maximize cable and minimize wires (in order to minimize running conduit indoors), run the cable to a junction box on the inside wall and run conduit through the wall to the outside. That box needs to be big enough for the splices. If I understand box fill rules correctly (don't count on that...) then using this calculator I get 30 inches if your cable and wires are hots + ground and 40 inches if you also have neutral.
Note that 6 AWG is about the limit for wire nuts, but there are a few that should work, such as the Ideal WT54 Blue or 66 Gray/Dark Blue.

Outdoor conduit is defined as a wet location - not "assumed" - and it tends to live up to the definition.
